# TypeInitialization Exception occurs while setting value to dependency property

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am developing a usercontrol in which i am registering dependency property as follows

```
    public string TextBoxHint
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextBoxHintProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextBoxHintProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxHintProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("TextBoxHint",
              typeof(string),
          typeof(AutoCompleteBox),
          new PropertyMetadata("Search"));
```

and i am using the usercontrol as follows in another page

```
 <localControls:AutoCompleteBox TextBoxHint="Search Task" />
```

Execution of above code is causing a TypeInitialization Exception at SetValue() function.

Can anybody point out what is wrong with the code ???

Thanks In advance...

Comment: Please post more details on exception. Any inner exceptions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Properties need a SetValue and GetValue function for that property so it should be something like this.

```
    public string ToolTipText 
    { 
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(ToolTipTextProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ToolTipTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static object GetToolTipText(DependencyObject target)
    {
        return (object)target.GetValue(ToolTipTextProperty);
    }

    public static void SetToolTipText(DependencyObject target, Object value)
    {
        target.SetValue(ToolTipTextProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolTipTextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ToolTipText", typeof(string), typeof(Controls.ProgressSlider), new PropertyMetadata("0%"));
```